# SimpleCursorAdapter with a cursor crashes but without works

Tags: android

I'm still learning the best ways to do thins in Android and I have a problem that I can't solve. I'm trying to understand for several hours, tried to find working snippets but I can't make this work.

I created a ContentProvider to encapsulate the database Access (I know I could have done this without ContentProviders but I want to learn :) ).

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, container, false);
    String[] projection = { CustomerDatabaseHelper.Col_name };
    int[] uiBindTo = { android.R.id.text1 };

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CustomerContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, null, null, null); // CustomerDatabaseHelper.Col_name+" ASC"
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(CUSTOMER_LIST_LOADER, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, cursor,
            projection, uiBindTo,
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

If I put null in the cursor parameter it works but doesn't provide me the list ordered. I created the cursor to sort my list. When I put it in the parameter the application crashes with the following message:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pt.com.hugodias.hstreportmanager/pt.com.hugodias.hstreportmanager.customer.CustomerListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment

I hope anyone could help me.

Hugo

Comment: Something is wrong in `XML file line #24`. The one that creates the Listview probably.

Comment: Check that I'm using the android simple listing, so the xml file of the listview is the simple_list_item_activated_1

Comment: Oh that yould be your error. The layout you create in `onCreateView` must contain a `ListView`, not the layout for a single item in that list. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199359/how-to-display-contacts-in-a-listview-in-android-for-android-api-11/18209421#18209421) is a small example how to use loaders + listviews.

Comment: At the bottom of the exception should be the real cause for it.

Comment: Problem solved. After more research I realized that nobody used the cursor in the SimpleCursorAdapter because it's been initialized in the onCreateLoader function. I placed the sort order in this function and now it works.