# Display ContactContracts Name, Email, Photo in ListView, using Fragment - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor, contactscontract

I have an activity that needs to display Android phone contacts into a `ListView` which is a fragment inside my `AddressBook.java` activity. I was able to get my list to display the names, but nothing else. I feel like I am close, but having a hard time with getting the views to work. In my XML files (I have 4), I have the activity XML (only has the fragment), the ListView XML (`contact_list_view.xml`), and then a typical row for the ListView which I call my Item XML (`contacts_list_item.xml`). But how do I connect all those views into my activity view? I think I have the fragment inside of the activity OK, since the list of names works, but not sure how to get a photo and email to display. I know I'm missing something in my main code too, `ContactFragments.java`.

One issue, is I had to filter my contacts by name, otherwise every email in every application on my phone would post, which is not what I want. I only want the contacts in my Android Contacts app to display, so I hope that doesn't inhibit the other details of the contacts from showing.

Below is my code, I don't show my `AddressBook.java` activity, because I only use the XML view to display my fragment in it, using the fragment tags (which works fine, because I do at least get the contact names).

I have searched far and wide for answers to this online, but there are so many parts, I could not find how to address my specific situation. I hope to use my code I already have and edit it minimally (versus implementing a whole new way to achieve this with other classes, etc). If you have any ideas, I'd be very thankful.

**ContactsFragment.java**

```
package org.azurespot.practiceapp.addressbook;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import com.example.practiceapp.R;

/*
 * Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199359/how-to-display-contacts-in-a-listview-in-android-for-android-api-11
 */

public class ContactsFragment extends ListFragment implements 
                                LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
    public ListView listView;
    public Cursor cursor;
    // Name should be displayed in the text1 TextView in item layout
    public static final String[] FROM = { ContactsContract.Contacts
                                                .DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
    private static final int[] TO = { android.R.id.text1 };
    private android.content.Context context;
    public View view;
    public static Uri uri;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // delete list if already there (old version)
        if (!(listView == null)){
            listView.setAdapter(null);
        }

        // create adapter once
        context = getActivity();
        int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        Cursor c = null; // there is no cursor yet
        int flags = 0; // no auto-requery! Loader requeries.

        // put List in adapter
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, FROM, TO, flags);


    } // end onCreate


    // columns requested from the database
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
            Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP
    };

    // this goes in the CursorLoader parameter list, it filters
    // out only those contacts who have a phone number
    private static final String SELECTION = 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";

    // Empty public constructor, required by the system
    public ContactsFragment() {}

    // A UI Fragment must inflate its View (all fragments must override onCreateView)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the fragment layout
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_view,
            container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list); 

        // set Contact photo to ImageView
        ContactsFragment frag = new ContactsFragment();
        ImageView thumb = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_thumbnail);
        frag.getPhotoUriFromID(Contacts._ID);
        thumb.setImageURI(uri);
        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // and tell loader manager to start loading
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

    }

    // a CursorLoader does a query in the background
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // load from the "Contacts table"
        Uri contentUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        // no sub-selection, no sort order, simply every row
        // projection says we want just the _id and the name column
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                PROJECTION,
                SELECTION,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        );
    }

    private Uri getPhotoUriFromID(String id) {
        try {
            Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver()
                    .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                    + "="
                                    + id
                                    + " AND "
                                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                    + "='"
                                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                    + "'", null, null);
            if (cur != null) {
                if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    return null; // no photo
                }
            } else {
                return null; // error in cursor process
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(id));
         uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
         return uri;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
         // Once cursor is loaded, give it to adapter
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // Delete the reference to the existing Cursor,
        // so it can recycle it
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

**contact_list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

**contacts_list_item**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/thumbnail" />

        <TextView 
          android:id='@+id/text_name'
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the getView() method of adapter and create a custom list view to display image, name and email.

Refer to this link for more details http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: Thanks Arjun, however I'm trying to pull from my `Contacts`, which is a whole other beast than just a `ListView` alone. Some tutorials say that `CursorLoader` has its own view, so I don't need to provide one. Then others say to get the photo/email from a query using my `Cursor`, accessing the `ContactContracts.Data` class table. Still researching, but if I find out more, I will note it here. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cursor is returning all the appropriate data, it looks like you just need to adjust some of the starting values when initializing the adapter.  Try updating the following:

```
public static final String[] FROM = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI };
private static final int[] TO = { R.id.text_name, R.id.contact_thumbnail };

int layout = R.layout.contact_list_item;
```

That should get your adapter showing both the image and the display name. Overriding the `getView()` method as suggested by Arjun Sna is not required since the `SimpleCursorAdapter` supports displaying both `TextView` and `ImageView`.  If you want to add the email, you need to update your XML to include another `TextView`, then add it's associating info to the FROM and TO arrays.